# allow multi value in managed metadata

Tags: managed-metadata

I have managed metadata field for which allow multi value is checked, I can select multiple value in edit form or new form but could not select multiple value in search form (custom form created)

Comment: Is this not by design? I would imagine you would try to search one term at a time if you knew what you were looking for, or use wildcard operators to expand your search?

Comment: for other managed metadata its working fine.